# Как предотвратить вывод дубликата записи в цикле?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте, у меня есть такой цикл:

```
 <% @session.number_of_session_places.times do |session| %>
 <% n = n+1 %>
  <div class="place_block" style=""><%= n %></div>
  <% @session.places.each do |p| %>
     <% if p.place_number == n %>
        <div class="place_block" style="background-color: black"><%= n %></div>
   <% end %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

По понятным причинам он выводит сначала блок

```
<div class="place_block" style=""><%= n %></div>
```

А потом

```
<div class="place_block" style="background-color: black"><%= n %></div>
```

С одинаковым номером.
Остальные записи выводятся без дубликатов. Подскажите как решить эту проблему, не могу логически продумать решение.

**Логика**: Есть сеанс в кинотеатре (@session), и есть количество мест в зале (number_of_session_places). Первый цикл выводит например 100 мест в зале. Далее есть таблица в БД (places), которая связана с таблицей сеансов (то есть в таблицу (places) добавляются только забронированные места, например 21 с указанием id сеанса). Выходит, что второй цикл проходит по всех забронированных местах для данного сеанса и выводит блок с черным фоном, если это место забронировано. Логика проста, если место забронировано - выводиться блок с стандартным фоном, иначе - блок с черным фоном.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код сначала выводит все места, сколько их есть, **в том числе** - забронированные, а затем - выводит только забронированные, с другим фоном, вот и дублирование. Добавьте условие, что места с обычным фоном выводить, только если брони **нет** - и будет вам счастье.

```
<% @session.number_of_session_places.times do |session| %>
  <% n = n+1 %>
  <% @session.places.each do |p| %>
    <% if p.place_number == n %> # Если место занято - выводим с фоном
      <div class="place_block" style="background-color: black"><%= n %></div>
    <% else %> # Иначе - без
      <div class="place_block" style=""><%= n %></div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Однако, так вы увеличиваете время генерации страницы: Ваш код производит `N*M` интераций, где `N` - число мест, а `M` - количество броней. Более того, вы не сможете закешировать эту часть вьюхи, так как она у вас получается динамической, и этот код будет срабатывать при каждом открытии страницы, что излишне.

Лучше, например, присвоить каждому `div`'у места свой `id` (опционально, пробежаться по дочерним элементам с указанным классом JS тоже может):

```
<div id="place_<%= n %>" class="place_block"><%= n %></div>
```

А результат работы цикла кешировать.

При загрузке страницы же, запускать JavaScript, получающий POST-запросом номера забронированных мест и меняющий для них класс на какой-нибудь `class="booked_place_block"`, с уже заданным чёрным фоном.

Тогда у вас будет лишь `N+M` интераций при первом заходе пользователя на страницу и `M` при последующих (число мест у вас не поменяется, только число забронированных), что повысит скорость работы вашего приложения, не говоря о возможности повесить скрипт проверки брони перезапускаться по таймеру, автоматически обновляя забронированные места.

Если не использовать кеширование, можно реализовать вывод посредством N+M интераций и на стороне сервера, применяя **следующую логику**, выработанную в ходе [мозгового штурма](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28413422#28413422) с [D-side](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/181100/d-side):

```
N=1
Цикл 1: Перебираем список забронированных мест, отсортированный по номерам мест
  Запоминаем номер текущей брони (M)
  Цикл 2: Создаём блоки-места по N, пока N<M, затем выходим из цикла 2
  Создаём бронированное место N=M
  Увеличиваем N на 1, следующая интерация цикла 1
Цикл 3: Создаём блоки-места по N, от M+1 до number_of_session_places, затем выходим из цикла 3
```

Comment: @Grundy  В предложенном выше варианте выводятся все записи по 2 раза) Но с JS идея хорошая. Спасибо

Comment: @Risto комментарии тут ни при чем, я их удалил, но все равно все записи выводятся 2 раза)

Comment: @MaximCherevatov значит, вы выводите блок где-то **вне** `if`а.

Comment: @Risto спасибо! Буду разбираться, пока на JS переделываю